# How to modify the 'totals' area in cart checkout area

Tags: cart

[image]

In the cart section of my Magento store i'm looking to modify these totals by adding a column (:) infront of each one.

So its laid out like this:

> Subtotal:
>
> Grand Total:

I cant figure out what file requires modification to change these.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look into two sections:

`app\design\frontend\yourtheme\default\template\tax\checkout\`

`app\design\frontend\yourtheme\default\template\checkout\total\`

Depending on your setup in tax configuration you have to manually add ':' after something like: `<?php echo $this->getTotal()->getTitle() ?` in:  `app\design\frontend\yourtheme\default\template\checkout\total\tax.phtml`

or something like:
`<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->getTotal()->getTitle()); ?>` in:  `app\design\frontend\youtheme\default\template\checkout\total\default.phtml`

So you can edit it into something like this:

```
<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->getTotal()->getTitle()) . ': '; ?>
```

or:

```
<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->getTotal()->getTitle()); ?>:
```

More specificaly, edit `app\design\frontend\yourtheme\default\template\tax\checkout\subtotal.phtml` (if you dont have one copy from base/default/ theme package)

`<td style="<?php echo $this->getStyle() ?>" class="a-right" colspan="<?php echo $this->getColspan(); ?>">
        <?php echo $this->getTotal()->getTitle() ?>:
    </td>`

Comment: Didn't work unfortunately :/ I tried editing both

Comment: Are you sure you're editing files in your active theme?

Comment: Fantastic. Your latest edit helped. Thanks :)

Comment: How would I have magento calculate tax when someone selects "Store Pick Up" as an option? Currently, it isn't calculating any tax for that method. However, If I select UPS it does..

Comment: @ElvaSandoval what's your tax settings based on - Billing Address/Shipping Origin?

Comment: @versedi it's currently set to "Shipping Address". So it calculates it based on where it will be delivered. We'd also still like to keep it that way for orders that will continue to ship.